# Unexplained load on linux vm - not processor, disk io / disk sleep

Tags: high-load

I have a 2 processor server with Centos7 that's showing unexplained bursty load. top, htop report matching load averages to the graph below but processes do not show up any matching load. No Ds in the process list. iotop seems ok. None of the usual gotchas so far as I can tell. Nginx is running on the server. There are a good number of files open (70k or so in total) however Nginx max files has been set with systemd up to 16k files. System max files is over 800k.

Can anyone suggest some other things to consider as I'm stumped?

Thanks!

[example load graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQHB.png)